# How to create instances with unique names?

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

According to [RunInstances](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/63440.htm) api docs I can set "UniqueSuffix"
 in the request to get a suffix of 001 to 999. On the other hand I'm allowed to only run 100 instances at a time.

This makes me think that if I'm creating instances on multiple batches, then number will continue after the highest number present today.

The issue though is that this does not happen. If I perform 2 requests with same name, then I get like:

- instance-name-001
- instance-name-002
- instance-name-001
- instance-name-002

So it restarts numbering. Is there anything I'm missing so that I can tell it to continue from some particular number or make it figure out highest number by itself?

P.S. while renaming after creation is feasible, I'd prefer to get unique names automatically instead of doing hundreds individual rename calls.

Comment: I deleted my answer. The Python SDK does not even support UniqueSuffix. This may be an oversight in the SDK or the feature is not going to be supported in future API releases. Are you using the REST API or an SDK (if so, which one)?

Comment: @JohnHanley, using the HTTP (I wouldn't call it REST) API directly.

Comment: Do you have support available thru the Console?

Comment: @JohnHanley, in fact I don't see any way to use this automatic unique suffix through console.

Comment: Can you open a technical support case in the Console?

Comment: @JohnHanley, good idea. Unfortunately I don't know Chinese :) Need to try with google translate or maybe some Chinese colleague would be willing to help. When you try to open a ticket is everything switched to Chinese for you?

Comment: My Console language is set to English. When I write to technical support in English they reply in English. I would suggest you open a support case for this one as access to the source code on the back end system is required.

Comment: @JohnHanley, trying but although console for me is also English, when I click on create ticket, most content except header goes to Chinese. Maybe master account settings matter as I'm only using a RAM user.